# Check if a datetime field occurs within a time period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to check if an assignment's due_date (datetime data type) occurs within the start and end of the current week (and later on within the next 2 weeks). The logic I need help with is the 'due_date: Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week' section. If you could help me write those two queries, that would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

```
@student_assignments = StudentAssignment.joins(:assignment).where("DATE(assignments.due_date) = ?", Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week).all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. One way to achieve it is:

```
@student_assignments = StudentAssignment.joins(:assignment).where("Date(assignments.due_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?", Date.today.beginning_of_week, Date.today.end_of_week)
```

Comment: I hope you enjoy Rails!